# Splitline Python String

Tags: python, web-scraping, split

I have a list of elements whose text is like the following:
`aSampleElementText = "Vraj Shroff\nIndia"` I want to have two lists now where the first list's element would have "Vraj Shroff" and the second list's element would have "India".

I looked at other posts about split and splitlines. However, my code below is not giving me expected results.

**Output:**

```
"V", 
"r"
```

**Desired output:**

```
"Vraj Shroff",
"India"
```

**My code:**

```
personalName = "Something" #first list
personalTitle = "Something" #second list
for i in range(len(names)-1) 
    #names is a list of elements (example above)
    #it is len - 1 becuase I don't want to do this to the first element of the list
    i += 1
    temp = names[i].text
    temp.splitlines()
    personName.append(temp[0])
    personTitle.append(temp[1])
```

Comment: What is `names`? And it looks like you are also missing a colon in your for loop.

Comment: @Rakesh I tried that. It does not work. I am new at Python. I am not really sure why that is the case.

Comment: @MoonCheesez it is a list of elements that I scraped. In the for loop, I am trying to access the title but in 2 lists. I will add the colon (it was present in the real code so that is not the issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
names = []
locations = []
a = ["Vraj Shroff\nIndia", "Vraj\nIndia", "Shroff\nxyz", "abd cvd\nUS"]

for i in a:
    b = i.splitlines()
    names.append(b[0])
    locations.append(b[1])

print(names)
print(locations)
```

output:

```
['Vraj Shroff', 'Vraj', 'Shroff', 'abd cvd']
['India', 'India', 'xyz', 'US']
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

names is a string. names[I] is the character corresponding to that index in the string. Hence you are getting this kind of output.

Do something like,

```
x = names.splitlines()
```

x will be the list with the elements.

Comment: `aSampleElementText.splitlines()`